# Azure Architecture pipeline for App which scan websites?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have crawlers running on VMs in Azure. After work is finished the Data crawled needs to be distributed to users across  the internet depending on their access level. What I need help with:
1. How to onboard users? My idea was to use Azure AD
2. How to organize pipeline from the crawlers to end users but some access rules and data filters need to be applied before using. What is the most effective way? My idea was to use Azure Functions and then Azure siglalR so my clients (desktop, mobile) can get data very fast. All that would be organized as a Logical app?

Please help. I am just starting my programming experience so sorry if my question is naive.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to onboard users?

[Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) would be a good choice for you. With Azure AD, it will be convenient to manage the users.

> 2. How to organize pipeline from the crawlers to end users but some access rules and data filters need to be applied before using.

Based on the description you provided, you will expose the data crawled as rest api, right? If so, you can integrate your api with Azure AD, then you can control the user access as you need. You can add app roles in your application and assign users and groups to roles, then different users will have different roles to access your api.

Reference:

[How to: Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

[Integrating with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-to-integrate)